# Submitting a Form with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am creating an edit page for my posts. I would prefer to create an html form instead of using FORM:: so I can really learn. I am having an issue when I try to submit the data to the right controller method.

The tutorial I am using says to use

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
```

Using my limited knowledge I tried to recreate this as

```
<form action="{!! Route::post('/posts', ['PostsController@update', $post->id]) !!}" method="POST">
```

underneath both I am using `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`

The error I get is `"

> Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Route could not be converted to
>   string (View:
>   /Users/Chris/code/chris/resources/views/posts/edit.blade.php)

My web.php file has `Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');` which as worked for everything else until now. In my contoller, my update method has

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    // Create Post
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Post Updated');
}
```

What would the correct action be to submit an update for my info?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: `Route::post` is for defining a route, not getting a route path, you just defined a new route and it returns a `Route` object, then you tried to echo that object.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

As Lagbox pointed out in the comments:

```
Route::post('/posts', ['PostsController@update', $post->id])
```

Is for defining the route in your routes file. To get the url you can do one of the following:

**Hard code the uri**

`action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}"`

**Use the `url()` helper**

`action="{{ url("posts/$post->id") }}"` or `action="{{ url("post", $post->id) }}"`

**Use the `route()` helper** (This will only work if you have given the route a name)

`action="{{ route('the-route-name', $post->id) }}"`

**Use the action helper**

`action="{{ action('PostsController@update', $post->id) }}"`

Here is a [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#urls) to the various url helpers. My main advice here would be to mainly stick to just using one of them for a project.

---

Furthermore, your code should work absolutely fine the way it is for now but usually with REST (or the way Laravel uses rest) you would make either a `PUT` or `PATCH` request for updating instead of a `POST` request.
However, standard html forms only support `GET` and `POST` so Laravel provides a way for you to [spoof the form method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the form action  with the following:
there are many solutions:

1- by using action method :

```
 <form action=" {!! action('PostsController@update',$post->id) !!}" method="POST">
```

2- by naming the route

```
<form action=" {!! route('route-name',$post->id) !!}" method="POST">
```

3- by using url method

```
<form action=" {!! url('/posts',$post->id) !!}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Lagbox. I used

```
<form action=" {!! route('route-name',$post->id) !!}" method="POST">
```

and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
edit.blade.php  file

```
           <form  action="{{url('user', [$users->id])}}" method="POST">             
             @csrf
              @method('PUT')
                 <div class="kt-portlet__body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form- 
                                control" value="{{$users->first_name}}">
                                @error('first_name')
                            <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ $message 
                              }}</strong>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form- 
                        control" value="{{$users->last_name}}">
                                    @error('last_name')
                                <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 
                        $message }}</strong>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form- 
                  control" id="password" value="{{$users->password}}">
                            @error('password')
                                <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 
                    $message }}</strong>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" 
                         name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" 
                   value="{{$users->password}}">
                                    @error('password_confirmation')
                                <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 
                           $message }}</strong>
                                    @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>   

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" 
                           value="{{$users->email}}">
                                @error('email')
                <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ $message }}</strong>
                                @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Mobile:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
                 class="form-control" value="{{$users->mobile_number}}">
                                    @error('mobile_number')
                                <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 
                            $message }}</strong>
                                    @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>   

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kt-portlet__foot">
                    <div class="kt-form__actions">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-brand" 
                   value="Update" >Update</button>
                                <a href="{{route('user.index')}}" class="btn btn- 
                           secondary">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </form>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         Routes=> web.php 
         Route::Resource('user','UsersController');
```